# Could not add pagination while fetching product as per category ID

Tags: rest-api, category-products

I am using end point API to fetch product as per category id and want to add pagination on it but in my code its not happening like this. I am explaining my code below.

```
$quoteUrl ='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/67/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&searchCriteria[currentPage]=2';
$chQuote = curl_init($quoteUrl);
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$quote = json_decode(curl_exec($chQuote));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($quote), True);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Here I need to fetch products as per category id(`i.e-67`) and add the pagination also means lets say per page user needs to display 2 product only. A per my code all products are coming and pagination is not working. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use below code:**

```
$quoteUrl ='http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=67&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1'; // Updating searchcriteria
$chQuote = curl_init($quoteUrl);
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
curl_setopt($chQuote, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$quote = json_decode(curl_exec($chQuote));
$array = json_decode(json_encode($quote->getBody()), True); // Change here

//I met this problem today and resolved it by using this:
if((count($array) + $page_size) >= ($current_page * $page_size)) {
   echo json_encode($array);
}else{
   echo $array= [];
}
```